# A chart where the line between points does not interpolate

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have an Excel spreadsheet showing the balance of a bank account over time. Each data-point is the balance of the account immediately after a transaction (so there might be several per day, with the date+time it happened, or there might be weeks with no data because the balance remained constant with no transactions).

When I create an X/Y Scatter or Line chart with Excel, the series line is comprised of straight lines directly between two sample points. This line, therefore, is meaningless because in real-life there is no "midpoint" between two balance points: the balance remains flat until the next transaction.

Is there any way to have Excel create charts with flat, horizontal lines between data points in a chart?

Answer (score 4):

How would you like that to look? Excel connects two data points with a line and it uses the shortest distance to do so. If you want the chart to show a horizontal line to the next day with data points, then you need to have the previous day's balance on the current day as a starting data point. See a sample data set and chart in the following screenshot.

[image]

Duplicating rows of data may not be practical. Another approach is to use a XY chart without lines and add error bars. You will need two helper columns, but these can be hidden if they mess up the worksheet.

First, the screenshot:
[image]

Each data point has an X and a Y error bar. The X error bars are set to plus, no cap and the custom value in the "duration" column, the Y error bars are set to plus, no cap and to the custom value in the "height" column.  Negative values will create a dropping line. Format the error bars with a thick line.

The formula in C2 is

```
=IF(A3>A2,A3-A2,0)
```

D2 has a manually entered 0  value, D3 and copied down has the formula

```
=B2-B3
```

You can format the data points with no markers, which will leave you with just the line.

Comment: The balance isn't associated with a date, but a specific point in time after a transaction took place, and there can be multiple transactions per day - I'm not keen on essentially duplicating the number of rows in my source data to satisfy Excel.

Comment: The chart you posted a screenshot of is the kind of chart I'm looking for, btw! :D ...I just hope there's a way of creating it without modifying the input data.

Comment: If you don't want to modify the data, add a helper column that creates what Excel needs.  If you want to do it in Excel and this is what you want the chart to look like, you have to work within Excel's limitations.

Comment: I've added another approach that does not require duplicate data rows.